# Connect to remote SSH with www-data user

Tags: ssh, debian

I want to open an SSH tunnel between one machine and another.
I don't have root access on the first machine, only access to the www-data account.
When I try to open an SSH tunnel to a second machine, I get the following error:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
> Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'. Warning: Permanently added
> '212.234.53.19' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission denied,
> please try again. Permission denied, please try again.
> sagaroth@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Is it possible to specify a folder where my user www-data has write permission instead of /var/www?

Thank you very much

Comment: The Error in that message is that the permission is denied to log into the remote server. You need to provide a valid private key.

Comment: So I have to get the key of my remote server and then specify it during the SSH connection?
Is it possible to specify another location?

Comment: Of course. Read the manual of the ssh client.

Comment: The problem is that I am not on a machine where I am root. And even if I temporarily change the HOME of my www-data user to point to a folder where I have write permissions, I still get a "Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'" error when I try to connect to my remot

Comment: You should not use `www-data` account for other purposes than running web servers. Create a dedicated user account for the tunnel purpose.